# Как работать в свернутом окне python?

Tags: python

есть один скрипт, зажимающий некоторые клавиши с некоторым промежутком времени для упрощения процесса в игре. Дело в том, что работает он только когда окно активно.
Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы нажатия клавиш передавались на прямую в процесс с игрой. Реально ли такое реализовать? И если да, подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку.

Comment: Windows, macos, linux?